# Python numpy percentile vs scipy percentileofscore

Tags: numpy, scipy, python-3.5

I am confused as to what I am doing incorrectly.

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

df
Out[29]: array([66., 69., 67., 75., 69., 69.])

val = 73.94
z1 = stats.percentileofscore(df, val)
print(z1)
Out[33]: 83.33333333333334

np.percentile(df, z1)
Out[34]: 69.999999999
```

I was expecting that `np.percentile(df, z1)` would give me back `val = 73.94`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're not quite understanding what `percentileofscore` and `percentile` *actually do*.  They are ***not*** inverses of each other.

---

From the docs for [`scipy.stats.percentileofscore`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.percentileofscore.html):

> The percentile rank of a score relative to a list of scores.
>
> A `percentileofscore` of, for example, 80% means that 80% of the scores in a are below the given score. In the case of gaps or ties, the exact definition depends on the optional keyword, kind.

So when you supply the value `73.94`, there are `5` elements of `df` that fall below that score, and `5/6` gives you your `83.3333%` result.

---

Now in the Notes for [`numpy.percentile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html):

> Given a vector V of length N, the q-th percentile of V is the value q/100 of the way from the minimum to the maximum in a sorted copy of V.

The default `interpolation` parameter is `'linear'` so:

> 'linear': `i + (j - i) * fraction`, where fraction is the fractional part of the index surrounded by i and j.

Since you have provided `83` as your input parameter, you're looking at a value `83/100` of the way from minimum to the maximum in your array.

If you're interested in digging through the source, you can find it [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/17ff82a7f3ca49717128b89d1a5560f4545fda0f/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L3856), but here is a simplified look at the calculation being done here:

```
ap = np.asarray(sorted(df))
Nx = df.shape[0]

indices = z1 / 100 * (Nx - 1)
indices_below = np.floor(indices).astype(int)
indices_above = indices_below + 1

weight_above = indices - indices_below
weight_below = 1 - weight_above

x1 = ap[b] * weight_below   # 57.50000000000004
x2 = ap[a] * weight_above   # 12.499999999999956

x1 + x2
```

```
70.0
```